# Saving thumbnail from memory to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an image read down into memory from an S3 bucket so I can extract the metadata and create a thumbnail.  I want to then upload that thumbnail from memory to another S3 bucket I created to store this information. I get the following error when I use the basic upload command:

> ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

```
client= boto3.client(
  's3',
  aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
  aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
  region_name='us-west-1')
sourcebucket = s3session.Bucket('original_bucket')
thumbbucket =  s3session.Bucket('thumbnail_bucket')

client.upload_file('./temp_files/temp_image.jpg', 'thumbnail_bukcet', 'my_key')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Connection reset by peer` is normally an indication of a networking problem rather than your code. Try it from a different computer or different network (eg home vs office) and it will probably work.

By the way, you should not be providing credentials within your code. Instead, keep credentials in a configuration file. See: [Credentials — Boto 3 documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html)